# Adobe CQ: custom error handler only works with .html extension

Tags: jsp, error-handling, http-status-code-404, aem

I'm trying to implement custom error handlers in AEM 5.6.  I've overlayed a custom handler for 404 errors under /apps/sling/servlet/errorhandler/404.jsp.  It works perfectly when the requested resource has the .html extension.  However, if I change the extension of the resource to anything else (including no extension at all), I am given the default 404 handler instead of my custom handler.

I don't see this behavior when deploying to an author instance.  It's only occurring on publish instances.

After quite a bit of searching Google, I've been able to find a single post from someone who has the same problem (http://help-forums.adobe.com/content/adobeforums/en/experience-manager-forum/adobe-experience-manager.topic.html/forum__rgmz-hi_i_added_custo.html).  However, the resolution, if any, is unclear to me.

Comment: Do you have a dispatcher in front of your publish instance? If yes, what http server is it (Apache or IIS)? depending on the dispatcher you need to configure how 404 are handled.

Comment: @Thomas Yes, we have a dispatcher in front of our publish instance.  We're using Apache as the HTTP server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your apache is delivering the 404 and is not taking the custom error message from CQ. I didn't try this myself, but I found a blog entry which might help you:
http://www.wemblog.com/2013/03/how-to-cache-error-page-in-cq.html